# Play 2.1.1 Bind a List<Class> from form

Tags: list, scala, interface, bind, playframework-2.1

I saw some similar questions, but I couldn't really understand any answers.
I have a problem with getting a list of  from a form. I've been doing it like this:

```
@Entity
public class Foo extends Model {
@Id
public Long id;

@Required
@Valid
@ManyToMany
public static List<Bar> bars = new ArrayList<Bar>();
}

@Entity
public class Bar extends Model{
    @Id
public int id;

@Required
public String name;
        // @Required
@Valid
@ManyToMany
public static List<Foo> foo = new ArrayList<Foo>();
}
```

And i've tried to make the interface based on answers i've read

```
@form(routes.Application.newFoo()) {
<select multiple name = "bar[].name">
        <option name = "bars[].name" value="option1">Option1</option>
        <option name = "bars[].name" value="option2">Option2</option>
        <option name = "bars[].name" value="option3">Option3</option>
    </select>
...
}
```

But when i try to do
    Form filledForm = fooForm.bindFromRequest();

```
    if (filledForm.hasErrors()) {
        return badRequest(views.html.index
                .render(Problem.all(), filledForm));
    } else {
        Foo foo = filledForm.get();
```

foo gets all other atributes, but the list is always empty.
What should I do?